# Simultaneous Gigabit writes over Network

Tags: networking

I have a gigabit network and every system on the network can access (read/write) data on a specific computer with a shared drive.
What I'm curious to understand is, if it is possible that multiple computers on the network can simultaneously read/write to the same location without dropping the speed for each connection?

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be a problem.  The bottleneck in this scenario isn't the hard drive.  It's the network.  Now perhaps if they are all trying to download files simultaneously, then you will see a slowdown.

Comment: That's the point, the bottleneck is the network and how can we improve it, is the question

Comment: you can't if they are all accessing the same computer.   i would make sure the settings are set correctly throughout the network.  If a single computer is running on 100mb vs gigabit, it will slow the entire network down to that speed for compatibility.   You could also look into adding a multi-port network card to the file server and each client gets its own port.